# Compile druid processing error with Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, druid

When i follow the [steps](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/build.html)  to build druid project locally, it throws error `[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?` while other components are successful.

**My environment**

IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Community Edition)

java version "1.8.0_333"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_333-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.333-b02, mixed mode)

Does anyone occur the same issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfNob.png)

Can anyone help to fix this issue?

Comment: did you check whether or not a jdk was provided? IntelliJ goes deeper in configuring all of that compared to other IDE's I've ussed in the past.